# How can I find-and-return an object in a Dequeue?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, queue, deque

I'm using a double-ended queue (java.util.Dequeue) and want to find an object in the queue and return it.

I'm currently using the `contains()` method to check if the queue contains the object, but don't know how to get the actual instance of the object found. The instance being searched is *not* the same instance, as I'm overriding the `equals()` method to test equality of a subset of class variables.

If it's not possible to do this using a Dequeue then what should I use instead? I need to push objects onto either end of a list and remove them from the start. And obviously be able to search for an object and get its instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little unclear to me if you wish to remove remove the object you are searching for, but, one possible solution is to get a iterator and, well, iterate though the list and manually do the equality check.

```
Iterator<YourClass> it = yourDeque.iterator();
YourClass foundInstance = null;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    YourClass obj = it.next();
    if(obj.equal(theInstanceYouAreSearchingFor)) {
        foundInstance = obj;
        break;
    }
}
if(foundInstance != null) {
   yourDeque.remove(foundInstance); // if you wish to remove it as well
}
```

Comment: Just need to get a reference to it. I suppose I'll just manually iterate then if there's no existing method.

Answer (score 0):

Using a linkedlist perhaps ? you would get methods to retrieve an element at an arbitrary position.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `LinkedList`, which implements `Deque`. You could then do:

```
Deque<Object> queue = new LinkedList<>();
// ...
int index = (LinkedList<Object> queue).indexOf(obj);
if (index != -1)
    (LinkedList<Object> queue).get(index);
```

Comment: If you're going to be casting to a specific implementation, either perform an `instanceof` check first (and have some fallback `else`), or (better for this case, I'd say), express that `queue` is a `LinkedList` in the type (replacing `Deque`).

Answer (score 0):

*(Just for fun)*

If you'd like to do it by index-based-iteration (a la `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`), you'd need `E get(int index)` and `E remove(int index)` methods. To have this, the `Deque` must also implement `List`. An implementation that satisfies this is `LinkedList`. Here's some generics hackery:

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(new LinkedList<>(asList("this", "is", "a", "test")));
        foo(new LinkedList<>(asList(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)));
    }

    public static <E, Delist extends Deque<E> & List<E>> void foo(Delist message) {
        System.out.println(message.get(1) + " " + message.getFirst() + " " + message.get(2) + " " + message.getLast());
    }
}
```